# Build expo Android app with TravisCI

Tags: android, react-native, travis-ci, expo

I try to build an expo React-Native Android app with TravisCI

Here is .travis.yml file:

`{
  "os": "linux",
  "dist": "trusty",
  "cache": {
    "directories": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
  },
  "group": "stable",
  "script": [
    "npm i -g exp",
    "exp login -u ... -p ...",
    "npm install",
    "npm test",
    "exp build:android"
  ],
  "node_js": "stable",
  "language": "node_js"
}`

In the end of the process everything is working fine and Travis is triggering the expo build.

`Waiting for build to complete. You can press Ctrl+C to exit.`

How can I react in Travis? Will I be able to do some conditional Input? Do I have to build the app in a completely way?

Comment: Do you tried with `expo build:android --non-interactive`?